# c# Unity creating object in the constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script:

```
        public  PlayState ()
        {
              HydroElectric ec = new HydroElectric();
        }
        public void ShowIt()
        {
            ec.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), ec.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");

            ec.t2Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 95, 100, 50), ec.t2Bool, "Turbina 3 MW");

            ec.t3Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 135, 100, 50), ec.t3Bool, "Turbina 1 MW");



            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), ec.prod.ToString ());      // PRODUCED ENERGY                             

            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 650, 10, 100, 25), TimeManager.gametime.ToString() );  // GAME TIME HOURS

            float test;

            if (LoadDiagram.diagramaCarga.TryGetValue(TimeManager.gametime, out test)) // Returns true.
            {
                GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 650, 275, 50, 25),  test.ToString ());
            }
        }
```

The problem is that I had to remove the Hydroelectric object out of the "ShowIt" method because it was being created everytime the toogle button was created, so I created a constructor to create the object, but now, the variable 'ec' is not recognized, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the variable only exists in the constructor:

```
public PlayState ()
{
    HydroElectric ec = new HydroElectric();
}
```

Which means that it's created, and then immediately lost as soon as the constructor is finished.  It sounds like you want it to be a class-level member:

```
private HydroElectric ec;

public PlayState ()
{
    ec = new HydroElectric();
}
```

That would make it available throughout the class, and would maintain a single instance of the variable for the instance of the class.

Comment: Got it, so I should not create variables in the constructor, just initialize them right/

Comment: @ClaudioA: You certainly *can* create variables in the constructor, just like in any method.  But they follow the same rules as any other method-scoped variables.